# How to find a homeomorphism between $X_{1}=(3,7)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $X_{2}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y^3=x^2\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X_{1}=(3,7)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $X_{2}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y^3=x^2\}$. Consider $X_1$ and $X_2$ as metric subspaces of 
$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the Euclidean metric) respectively.

I want to show that there is a homeomorphism between $X_1$ and $X_2$ but I'm really struggling to visualise a continuous, bijective function between the two, since the graph of $X_2$ goes beyond the small domain of $X_1$.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Any open interval is homeomorphic to all of $\mathbb{R}$ (for example $\tan$ maps $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $(-\infty, \infty)$, so the domains of $X_1$ and $X_2$ seeming so different is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps:

- Make a homeomorphism between $(3,7)$ and $\mathbb R$. $x\mapsto\tan\frac{(x-5)\pi}{4}$ would do the job:

  - We subtract $5$ to get a map to $(-2,2)$,
  - Multiply by $\pi$ to get to $(-2\pi,2\pi)$,
  - Divide by $4$ to get to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and
  - Use $\tan$ to map to the whole $\mathbb R$.
- Make a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and your graph: $x\mapsto (x,\sqrt[3]{x^2})$ can work.

Now all we need is to compose those two.

Comment: Aha I completely forgot about compositions, thank you very much!